# Eclipse 3.8 startup bar and ui configuration

Tags: eclipse, configuration, ide, progress-bar, startup

I recently "upgraded" from Eclipse 3.7 to 3.8, and i miss the PROGRESS ON STARTUP and the ENHANCED STYLE TABS on the IDE.

Can anyone point where can i change these configs?

Checked the **plugin_customization.ini** on the following plugins:
org.eclipse.sdk_3.8.2.v201301310800
org.eclipse.platform_3.8.2.v201301310800

And found:
org.eclipse.ui/SHOW_TRADITIONAL_STYLE_TABS=**false**
org.eclipse.ui/SHOW_PROGRESS_ON_STARTUP=**true**

So, it's an Eclipse 3.8 BUG or i'm i missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the eclipse.ini was the culprit.

The INI from the 3.7 has side effects on 3.8!

This cannot be present in 3.8 INI:

**-product

org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product**